# How to dump data from Oracle to MySql

Tags: mysql, oracle

In my migration project, i need to dump the data from oracle to mysql.

So is there any utility or way i can do this operation?

The data dump file in the form of .dmp.

Comment: Maybe you would get more/better results if you ask this question on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks Ronald for your direction.